# Sms BroadcastReceiver stops working after a while

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms

I am devloping an android app which receives incoming sms.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
```

I have this permission in my manifest(I excluded the Read sms permission because I don't want to read from the sms database).

```
<receiver android:name=".receivers.SmsReceiver" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

I also registered the receiver in the manifest like in above. From what I have read the above code should be enough to receive the sms broadcast even when the app is not running.

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
    String sender = null;
    String message = null;
    String time = null;
    String date = null;
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) data.get("pdus");
        String format = (String) data.get("format");
        for(int i=0;i<pdus.length;i++){
            SmsMessage msg = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i],format);
            sender = msg.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
            message = msg.getDisplayMessageBody();
            long dt = msg.getTimestampMillis();
            time = String.valueOf(dt)+"time";
            date = String.valueOf(dt)+"date";

        }
    }
    else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19){
        SmsMessage[] msgs = Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent);
        for(int i=0;i<msgs.length;i++){
            SmsMessage msg = msgs[i];
            sender = msg.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
            message = msg.getDisplayMessageBody();
            long dt = msg.getTimestampMillis();
            time = String.valueOf(dt)+"time";
            date = String.valueOf(dt)+"date";

        }

    }
    else{
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) data.get("pdus");
        for(int i=0; i<pdus.length; i++){
            SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            sender = smsMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
            message = smsMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
            long dt  = smsMessage.getTimestampMillis();
            time = String.valueOf(dt)+"time";
            date = String.valueOf(dt)+"date";

        }
    }

    Dbhelper dbhelper = new Dbhelper(context);
    Command command = new Command(sender,message,date,time);
    dbhelper.insertCommand(command);
    if(LogFragment.commands != null){
        LogFragment.commands.add(command);
        LogFragment.update();
    }

}
```

}

This is my Smsreceiver class, when the sms is received it is stored in a separate database. Everything works fine when the app is launched, incoming sms is received and stored in the database even after I kill the app the broadcast receiver still works for a while then like after an hour it stops working, any incoming sms after that is not received by my broadcast receiver. I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: what is the compile sdk version? and why dont you try register broadcast with context ?

Comment: Registering broadcast with context means it is only going to work when the app is running i.e when the context is not null. My compile sdk version is 25 same with the target sdk version

Comment: Best way is to start a service from broadcast receiver... i mean don't do too much work in onReceive method. Sometimes it could skip the control as i read some where. So, try to put just log print and than try with same code if executed or not...

Comment: @SRBbans sorry I don't fully understand you. Are you saying the onReceive method is always called but the method for storing the sms into the database is skipped??

Comment: @Shaibu yes.. but i'm not fully sure about that.. you can give it a try.. put log there and comment the rest code.. then see if it is called or not.

Comment: Did you ever get this solved? I'm having the same problem...

Comment: @Shaibu any luck yet? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @Shaibu any luck?

Comment: @Magnus any luck? I guess its after upgrading something in android studio !!!

Comment: @NarendraSingh Singh any luck?